# Any tools to find order of .o files to be linked in a project using gcc

Tags: linux, visual-c++, gcc, linker, porting

I am porting vc++ project to work on the Linux platform i am using g++ as my compiler. i resolved compiling issues on g++ and able to generate .o files for every source file in vc++ project now i have to link them to produce final executable 
i can do that by

g++ file1.o file2.o -o file.out

but when i do that in my make file and execute it a lot of ld errors are coming dueto dependency's

is there any way i can figure it out order of giving the object files ?
are there any tools to do that or any vc++ project files which have the order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "vc++", but you are using "gcc" (usually that would be g++").  Likely you are missing one or more libraries, which you would specify with a "-l" option (documented as part of [ld](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) as well as gcc).

The distinction is important, because each wrapper (gcc and g++) adds the corresponding runtime library to the options it passes to *ld*.

The order of shared libraries (the most common form with Linux) supposedly does not matter (the linker makes two passes to resolve symbols).  A while back, before shared libraries were common, I wrote a program (named `liborder`, and mentioned [here](http://invisible-island.net/autoconf/my-autoconf/CHANGES)) which analyzes a collection of ".o" objects and "-l" (static libraries) to print a recommended order for the "-l" options. That was workable for small programs, but not for complex ones.  For example, Oracle's runtime libraries around 20 years ago were all static, and one needed a list of 15-20 libraries in the proper order to successfully link.  My program could not handle that.  However, since then, shared libraries (which do not have the problem with ordering) are common enough that I have not bothered to package `liborder` for use by others (it's still on a to-do list with a dozen other programs).

If your program uses symbols which are *not* in the standard library for C/C++, then you have to determine that yourself.  I suppose one could have a program that searches all of the development libraries for a given symbol, but that appears wasteful, since only a tiny fraction would be pertinent.  I see 200 of these in my /usr/lib.

Rather, I make it easy for me to see what my program is missing, by presenting the symbols from *nm* in readable form -

For C, I use scripts ([here](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#general_scripts) as "externs" and "imports") to check which symbols are *exported* or *imported* from a collection of ".o" files.  The scripts use the output of the [nm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) program, which shows the given symbols.

For C++, there's an option "-C" of nm which shows the unmangled names of symbols.

Comment: using the scripts v have to manually determine the order of linking  are there any tools which can automate the process ?

Comment: There are a lot of libraries - but on Linux, library *order* does not matter much.

Comment: A builder like [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) can automatize the build, and you should learn how to use it.

Comment: Really?  Some details might help support that statement.